# Windows Azure Notification Hubs plugin for Apache Cordova on PhoneGap App - WindowsAzure is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, azure, phonegap-plugins

I added Windows Azure Notification Hubs plugin for Apache Cordova to a simple PhoneGap app by

```js
phonegap plugin add https://github.com/PhonegapProjects/cordova-plugin-azure-notificationhub.git
```

Then I tried calling Service bus by using below code

```js
var connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://msopentech.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=vWgSeiB5WI3lT6ymUsQh5/upLZa0PHUYB+Hmya/RT3k=";
 var notificationHubPath = "test";

        var hub = new WindowsAzure.Messaging.NotificationHub(notificationHubPath, connectionString);
```

This results in **"WindowsAzure is not defined error"**. I am not sure how to add the Azure Notification plugin to the PhoneGap project.
Note:
 I am testing this on browser using phonegap serve

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

See this sample project: https://github.com/klingdigital/cordova-azure-push-notificationhub-crossplatform-sample

I had this trouble too, but the script scripts\Pushman.js solved.

Comment: Thank you rd_rscan. Can you used it in both IOS and Android devices? The most importing question is: is it working properly?